# Window OpenCV in python in terminal

Tags: python, opencv, terminal

I am using vim to write Python codes, and I am using OpenCV for image processing. I wonder if there is a way to create and show windows like

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('totoro.jpg')
cv2.imshow(img)
```

If I run the codes directly in Python in terminal, nothing will happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, you need to call `cv2.waitKey` to see the image window.

```
...
cv2.imshow('window name', img)
cv2.waitKey()
```